# Azure EventGrid Advanced Filter where Subject does not contain string

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, advanced-filter

**Scenario:**

- EventGrid-triggered Azure Function
- EventGrid messages created when blobs uploaded to any container within a Storage Account
- I am successfully limiting EventGrid messages, using Advanced Filters, for the following FileTypes

**Key:** Subject

**Operator:** String ends with

**Value:** .txt, .json etc.

[image]

I now need to filter which *Blob Containers* trigger an EventGrid message.

**Sample EventGrid Subject:**

```
"subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/vnd-test/blobs/sample.zip"
```

**How do I use EventGrid Advanced Filters to NOT TRIGGER when blobs are uploaded to `vnd-test` container?**

**Tried:**

**Key:** Subject

**Operator:** String is not in

**Value:** vnd-test

But the EventGrid message still fires and triggers the Function.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Your understand is wrong. Condition was been meeted, so function been triggered is expected. Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: The AEG Advanced filtering doesn't support an operation either **NOT** or **StringNotContains** for handling your requirements, please vote the feedback to the AEG team initiated over 2 years ago: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/35997100-advancedfilters-2018-09-15-preview-add-more-op Note, that in the case of known less than 25 containers, use the operation **StringContains** with a specific container names, see more details about the limits. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#limitations

Comment: Thank you @Roman. I will try **StringContains**

Comment: @Roman, I couldn't get the **StringContains** Advanced Filter to work. Ended up handling this in my application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use EventGrid Advanced Filters to NOT TRIGGER when blobs are
> uploaded to vnd-test container?

I know what you want to do, but now there is no corresponding operatorto implement your idea in the event grid.

I can briefly explain to you why the event grid does not refuse to receive events sent to the vnd-test container.

The structure of blob created event is like below:

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/test-container/blobs/new-file.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 524288,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/new-file.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

When you set **`subject`** **`string is not in`** **`["vnd-test"]`**, in fact it is doing:

For example, if a file named 111.txt been sended to vnd-test. It conducts the following thought process:

1, Is `/blobServices/default/containers/vnd-test/111.txt` one of the elements of the collection `["vnd-test"]`?

2, No, it is not. That is great! I will accept this event because it meets the condition.

3, event grid was very happy to create the blobcreated event and send this event to the function endpoint, so your function is triggered

It does not compare part of the string inside the subject with vnd-test, but uses the entire subject to compare with vnd-test. However, the subject is refined to the blob level, how can it be possible to write every possible blob to the collection? The current operator does not support your idea.

Comment: Thank you @BowmanZhu, this makes sense. Looks like RomanKiss has a method that could work (up to 25 limit).

Comment: @ericOnline Hi, if my answer answered your question. Can you mark it as the answer to end this question?:) If you want, you can use the StringContains operator.